# DropDownList SelectIndexChanged not working?

Tags: asp.net

This seems to be a common problem. I have tried different solutions but its still not working. This is my code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Artist *</label>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="artistDropdown" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="artistDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:TextBox ID="mytest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="artistDropdown" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Required Field" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
  <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" CssClass="help-block" Visible="False">Cant select Artist with no Manager</asp:Label>
</div>
```

**Function: OnSelectedIndexChanged**

```
protected void artistDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

string selectedArtist = artistDropdown.SelectedValue;
mytest.Text = selectedArtist;
string query = "Select [Manager ID] from Artist Where ID = '" + selectedArtist + "'";

string myConnection = dbController.connectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnection);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
conn.Open();
object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (obj is System.DBNull)
{
    artistDropdown.SelectedValue = "";
    lblMessage.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    lblMessage.Visible = false;
}
conn.Close();
}
```

I am loading DropDownList in `Page_Load()` function and `AutoPostBack="True"` is set for DropDownList.

I have also made a TextBox which is being set to the selectedValue from DropDownList to check if on OnSelectedIndexChanged is firing. But text box remains empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you change `mytest.Text = selectedArtist;` to `mytest.Text = selectedArtist + DateTime.Now.ToString();`? I suspect that the `Values` in `artistDropdown` are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the binding of your dropdown in the if (!postback) {} ?

If you rebind the list after every postback, you get the value of the first list item when you reach the artistDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged event. 
If this item has an empty string value...

Comment: Yes I am binding DDL in if(!postback)